# web.py no socket could be created error

Tags: python, sockets, web.py

When I run this helloworld code I get a "No socket could be created" error.

```
import web

urls = ("/.*", "hello")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Hello, world!'


app.run()
```

The same cod works fine if I enclose the call to app.run() inside of an if statement like this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

My understanding is that it shouldn't make any difference. Anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

if you run a `py` file in command line,the default `__name__` attribute will be `__main__`,and your code is executed from top to bottom.You can refer to this question [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: I understand that. But shouldn't the behavior be equivalent with or without the app.run() being enclosed in an if statement given that I am running from the command line?